# useDapp useCall useEffect

Tags: reactjs, web3js, usedapp

I need call contract function in useEffect

How to get same result with useDapp ? Any example of this case ?

```
// define standard web3 call
const feth = async (address) => {
  const contract = new.web3.eth.Contract(ContractAddress, ContractABI)
  const response = await contract.methods.getDataByUserAddress(address).call()
  return response
}

// call when page open
useEffect(() => {
    if(isAddress(props.match.params.address))
      fetch(props.match.params.address)
}, [props.match.params.address]);
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, it is about this library - [useDApp](https://usedapp.io/).

In your example you use `web3.js`, but as I understood from the documentation for `useDApp`, it works with `ethers.js`.

To use the library you need to install it and ethers:

```bash
npm install @usedapp/core ethers
```

Further it is quite simple, here is a sample from the documentation with some changes for your question:

```js
const UserAddressComponent = (props: { chainId: number, address: string }) => {
  const wethAddress = WETH_ADDRESSES[props.chainId]
  const wethInterface = new utils.Interface(WethAbi)
  const contract = new Contract(wethAddress, wethInterface)

  const { state, send } = useContractFunction(contract, 'getDataByUserAddress')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAddress(props.address)) {
      send(props.address)
    }
  }, [props.address]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Status: {state.status}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The basic idea here is that we use the `useContractFunction` hook which allows us to send a transaction that executes a function of a contract on a blockchain.

To use `useContractFunction` you must provide a contract object from the `ether.js` library and a string function name.

It returns an object, which you can destruct and get from there `send` method and `state` object:

- `send` is used to make requests and matches all arguments to solidity contract arguments.
- `state` object can be used to track the status of a transaction.

You can read more about all the hooks and methods in the [documentation](https://usedapp-docs.netlify.app/docs/Guides/Transactions/Contract%20Functions#example) of the library

Comment: Your answer looks like it was created by ChatGPT, which is [currently banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035). Please check out [this Meta FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: @Fastnlight but there is nothing from chatGPT, all the information is taken from the documentation and slightly adapted to the user's question

Comment: The section at the bottom (`I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.`) is known to be included in ChatGPT answers. If you in fact did not use ChatGPT, I recommend you remove that section to prevent other users from questioning your answer. However, the formatting of the answer is very similar to that of ChatGPT, so some users may still call it out.

Comment: @Fastnlight I see your point, I'll change my answer, thank you